# Python client socket detect if server has died

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp

i have a TCP Client on a Raspberry Pi connecting to a network Printer:

```
   sock = socket.socket(sockwt.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.settimeout(5)
   sock.connect((ip,port))
```

My Problem ist now that the socket stays open when I unplug the network cable or turn off the printer.
And sending data does not fail -
`sock.send(data)` 
always returns the correct number of bytes

So i tried to add a keep alive

```
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 3)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 2)
```

but that changes nothing.

So why does the sock.send(data) not fail, when the server has died?
or: how can i make sock.send fail?

When I send data and the server has died, there should be no ACK. Why do I not get a information about that?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that this is a TCP thing. You have a stream socket, and you asked for sending some bytes. A correct answer only means that the bytes could be sent but makes no guarantees for the peer receiving them. It is necessary because you could have a complex network with a number of switches and routers on the path.

Under normal circumstances, you should get an error at a time but possibly after sending some packets.

What could be done?

Some printer protocols have provision for commands close to *Are You There?* or *Who Are You?* that allow the client to ask the server for a message. That would be a robust way to make sure that the printer is ready.